# Tilling a image with a bitmap xml doesn't work

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview, tile, tiling

This is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/up_margin"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ticket_up_tile"/>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_below="@id/up_margin"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:layout_margin="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/origin"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/gray32"
        android:textSize="17dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/destination"
        android:layout_below="@id/origin"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:translationY="-5dp"
        android:textColor="@color/gray32"
        android:textSize="17dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_below="@id/destination"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/gray32"
        android:textSize="28dp"
        android:text="@string/intro.mileage"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/line1"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0.5dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/title"
        android:background="@color/gray32"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/line1"
        android:id="@+id/prices_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </RelativeLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/line2"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0.5dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/prices_container"
        android:background="@color/gray32"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dismiss"
        android:layout_below="@id/line2"
        android:textColor="@color/background"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/Dismiss"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/down_margin"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/container"
    android:src="@drawable/ticket_down_tile"/>
```

I have at the beginning and the end an Image that I need to be tiled.
I set on it a drawable which I created:

```
<bitmap
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:tileMode="repeat"
android:src="@drawable/popup_ticket_up"/>
```

As you can see, it has tileMode on Repeat. Also the imageViews, both are matching the parrent in width. 
This is what I get back:
[image: As you can see, it does not tile]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `bitmap` as a `background` to your container (or on the `View` you want) instead of adding it as a `src` to an `ImageView`